# Creating JSON with python cgi returns only one row

Tags: python, sql, json, oracle, cgi

I am trying to create a json from my sql query using python cgi, however it only returns one row in my table, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It probably has to do with my list declaration but I am not sure how to fix this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
import json
import cx_Oracle
cgitb.enable()


fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

with open("../../password.txt", 'r') as pwf:
pw=pwf.read().strip()



imagequery = """ 
SELECT PLACENAME_ID, COMMENT FROM PLACENAMES
"""
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn="gen", user="7", password=pw)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(imagequery)

place_id = []
comment = []
for row in c:
    place_id =row[0]
    comment = row[1]



result = {}
result['place_id'] = place_id
result['comment'] = comment

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")



sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result,indent=1))
sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.stdout.close()
```

Result

```
{
 "place_id": 5326,
"comment": "Graveyard"
}
```

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. What you have posted is invalid and wouldn't even run.

Comment: @DanielRoseman my bad, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create  dictionary out of each entry and append it to an array. Your JSON will then contain an array with all the database entries.

```
places=[]
for row in c:
    place = {}
    place['place_id'] = row[0]
    place['comment'] = row[1]
    places.append(place)



result = {}
result['places'] = places
```